# Wordpress plugin Google map API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a wp plugin, and when I use it to search address I get the answer....

Google geocoding service did not respond with OK status. Requested URL: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&language=pt-BR&address=floresta&key=AIzaSyD5Oy_MPNX_lgUbV2jmYleOZ4QTwx2fL-E Returned status: REQUEST_DENIED

Any thing wrong?

Comment: Are you using maps for business or standard maps API?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the error message?

```
This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.
```

You need to substitute your own API key, you can find instructions on how to generate one [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#api_key).